# Do all 11 fielders need to be in the field?

Tags: rules, cricket, formations

I was just wondering if there is a rule about how many fielders need to remain in the ground during a cricket match.

Can't the fielding captain argue that we do not need the 11th man on the field, for whatever reasons?

Also, will the umpire call no ball if a fielder is standing just outside the boundary before the ball is delivered?

Comment: Seems a fair question; not sure for the reason behind the downvotes.

Answer (score 6):

There is **no requirement** to have 11 fielders on the field at all times. [Law 1 (The players)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-1-the-players/) makes provision for the number of players per team to be varied by agreement of the captains:

> By agreement a match may be played between sides of fewer than, or more than, eleven players, but not more than eleven players may field at any time.

A no-ball will **not** be called if a fielder leaves the field or fails to takes the field. [Law 2.1 (Substitutes and runners)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-2-substitutes-and-runners-batsman-or-fielder-leaving-the-field-batsman-retiring-or-batsman-commencing-innings/) specifically states that a fielder may leave the field, thereby leaving fewer than 11 fielders on the field:

> A player wishing to change his shirt, boots, etc. shall leave the field to do so. No substitute shall be allowed for him.

However, according to [Law 2.5 (Fielder absent or leaving the field)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-2-substitutes-and-runners-batsman-or-fielder-leaving-the-field-batsman-retiring-or-batsman-commencing-innings/), she/he may not return without the consent of the umpire (which will be given as soon as possible). If she/he does so and touches the ball while in play, the umpire will award **penalty runs** under [Law 2.6 (Player returning without permission)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-2-substitutes-and-runners-batsman-or-fielder-leaving-the-field-batsman-retiring-or-batsman-commencing-innings/):

> If a player comes on to the field of play in contravention of 5(b) above and comes into contact with the ball while it is in play [...] the ball shall immediately become dead and the umpire shall award 5 penalty runs to the batting side.